# How can I change the Service Control Manager Access Rights for a user/group?

Tags: windows, security, service, elevated-privileges, access-rights

I need to query the status of a service in a remote computer and I can't use a admin user, I need to create a user with the least privileges necessary to do that.

Looking at the [Service Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx#access_rights_for_the_service_control_manager), I think a user with the SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE and the SC_MANAGER_CONNECT rights will be sufficient.

Am I right? How can I grant this access rights to a user/group?